# Error in UseMethod("invoke"): no applicable method for 'invoke' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: apache-spark, sample, sparklyr, collect

I'm trying to run a sample of the data. It is a Large tbl_spark (2 elemets, 1.4mb), and the class is "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"

my code is as follows

```
temp <- sdf_sample(table, fraction = 0.01) %>% collect()
```

Then I got this error:
Error in UseMethod("invoke"): no applicable method for 'invoke' applied to an object of class "character"

Then I run the same thing again and got:
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Please help